# Manipulate: SetterBar with list of functions

Tags: manipulate

From the documentation:

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}}]
```

How do I include a function like $1/x$ or $x^2$, etc. in that list?

I (unsuccessfully) tried `1/#` and `#^2`.

Comment: Maybe `#^2 & -> x^2, 1/# & -> 1/x`, as you also might want the labels for the pure functions?

Comment: @PinguinDirk: ugh, I had forgotten my closing `&`. Thanks. If you post as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in comments, here's a possible approach:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, #^2 & -> x^2, 
1/# & -> "1/x"}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x],{x,0,2 Pi}],{f,{Sin[#]^2 &,#^2&,Cos,Tan,Cot}}]
```

David.