# SetterBar divider style in Manipulate on a Mac

Tags: manipulate, formatting, mac-os-x

MMA 9.0.1 MacOSX "Mavericks".  This issue is apparently mac specific.

The issue of this post is illustrated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18882/4811), for example.  In a `SetterBar` control straight out of a `Manipulate`, there are no dividers, though the default appearance in other contexts is to have them.  I prefer to have them and don't know why that design decision has been made, but anyway.  I found a simple way to restore them using the `Paneled` option for `Manipulate` (which happened to produce other beneficial styling effects):

```
Manipulate[
  Panel@view, {{view, 3, "Fruit:"}, 
    {1 -> "Apples", 2 -> "Pears", 3 -> "Medlars"}, SetterBar}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> True]

Manipulate[
  Panel@view, {{view, 3, "Fruit:"}, 
    {1 -> "Apples", 2 -> "Pears", 3 -> "Medlars"}, SetterBar}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None,  Paneled -> False]

Panel@
Manipulate[
  Panel@view, {{view, 3, "Fruit:"}, 
    {1 -> "Apples", 2 -> "Pears", 3 -> "Medlars"}, SetterBar}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> False]
```

[image: Output of code above]

My question: is there a better way to get the dividers back from within a `Manipulate`?

Comment: I have them in the three cases [see here](http://i.imgur.com/rwyoDzL.png).

Comment: I can reproduce it on V9.0.1 Mac OS 10.8.5.

Comment: @Öskå maybe a Mac issue then.

Comment: @fairflow then you can add the `osx` tag :)

Comment: Actually the divider is there, but it's barely visible.

Comment: @Szabolcs goodness, you are right.  My eyesight isn't that good after decades of screen-staring... :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is a TabView. It will certainly work for your toy problem, but whether it has the functionality you need for your real problem is ... well ... problematic. Here is an implementation of your toy.

```
Module[{items, lbls, rules},
  items = Panel[#] & /@ Range@3;
  lbls = {"Pears", "Peaches", "Pomegranates"};
  rules = Thread[Rule[lbls, items]];
  Panel @ TabView[rules, 2,
    ImageSize -> 200,
    Alignment -> {Center, Center},
    ControlPlacement -> {Top, Center}]]
```

[image: TabView]

Comment: Actually this approach works fine within the _first_ argument to `Manipulate`, I can get a `TabView` controlled by a variable of the `Manipulate`, and which also sets this variable as a `SetterBar` would. But I don't see how to get a `Control` which is also a `TabView` within the _2nd_ argument to `Manipulate`, which is what I need for layout purposes.  I'm producing CDF's btw.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but

```
Panel@
 Manipulate[
  Panel@view, {{view, 3, "Fruit:"}, 
     {1 -> "Apples", 2 -> "Pears", 3 -> "Medlars"}, SetterBar}, 
   AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> False]
```

is the best I've found that allows me to put my view into the 2nd argument (control section) of `Manipulate`, though I appreciate m_goldberg's suggestion.  With apologies, I plan to accept this answer instead.

Comment: This isn't yet a good answer.  I'll post an answer that shows exactly what I need, i.e. a nice-looking view in the control section of a `Manipulate`